# How to join splines

Tags: bezier-curves, vertices

Right now I'm facing the problem where I have to connect two vertices.
[image]

As it is shown on the picture the vertices are related to the same spline, so I can't use "Make segment" tool. Also I can't use "Toggle cyclic", because the model doesn't work properly when I export it. 
Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Select both Vertices/Control Points on either side of the gap and press F (fill)

Edit:  Just looked up the hotkey, F, and it is actually called "make segment" which you say you can't use, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like, you have Poly spline type form the right, and Bezier from the left.

You can't connect splines with different types.

First you need to change spline type Curve > Set Spline Type.

Comment: As I said both vertices relate to the same spline, so if I change spline type it will change for every vertex.